# While loop in Python 3.5 repeats asking for input instead of giving out an value that is assigned to the input in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I tried to replicate an example from a Python book, that shows how to convert a textfile to a dictionary and ask for translations via the input function.

My Problem is now that this Programm won't give me the translation for a given valid input that is in the dictionary. If I use an `if True` instead of the while loop it however does. I tried rearranging the code but it will still repeat asking me for input however.

Here is the code that causes this Problem:

```
    genetischercode={}

    while True:
      triplet=input("Geben sie ein basentriplet ein: ")

    with open("C:\\Users\\Christian\\Desktop\\Python-Programme\\Genetischer Code.txt","r") as fobj:
      for line in fobj:

      line=line.strip()
      Zuordnung=line.split( )
      genetischercode[Zuordnung[0]]=Zuordnung[1]


    if triplet in genetischercode:
     print("Die korrespondierende Aminosäure ist: ",genetischercode[triplet])
    else:
      print("Bitte geben sie ein gültiges Triplet ein: ")
```

What now happens ist that instead of `if triplet in genetischer code:` or `else:` getting triggered, the program will repeat asking for input for the variable `triplet`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you fix the indentation? It's hard to guess what's this supposed to do. The first `while True` loop makes an infinite loop but I guess that's not what you're going for. Or is this the problem?

Comment: `while True` means keep going as long as `True` is `True`. The loop will never end. If you want all of the code to run, indent it so that it is within this loop.

Comment: Thanks for your interest guys, i fixed the indentation and the code now works properly :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `if triplet in…` and following lines into the loop body by placing it into right place with increased indent. (Note that indents are very important in Python programming as it is the only way to make blocks of code used in loops, `if`s and so on.)

```
genetischercode={}

# we have to generate the dictionary only once
with open("C:\\Users\\Christian\\Desktop\\Python-Programme\\Genetischer Code.txt","r") as fobj:
  for line in fobj:

      line=line.strip()
      Zuordnung=line.split( )
      genetischercode[Zuordnung[0]]=Zuordnung[1]
# now enter infinite loop
while True:
  triplet=input("Geben sie ein basentriplet ein: ")

  # you probably want some way to exit the loop
  if triplet == 'stop':
      break

  if triplet in genetischercode:
      print("Die korrespondierende Aminosäure ist: ",genetischercode[triplet])
  else:
      print("Bitte geben sie ein gültiges Triplet ein: ")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ilya :-)!

Comment: If the answer answers your question, you can 'accept' it by clicking on check mark to the left of the answer.